# Printing whole string that contains multiple NUL

Tags: c, string

```
 char *string1;                  
 int i; 
 string1=(char*)malloc(14*sizeof(char));
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 string1[i]=i+65;
 string1[10]=0;
 string1[11]=65;
 string1[12]=67;
 str[13]=0;  
 printf("%s",string1);
```

But the output is till the first NUL. Is it possible to print it till the last NUL with out using loop?

Comment: Note that you're accessing out of bounds on array-indexes > 9

Comment: @novice little you code is totally invalid. You allocated only 9 characters but are trying to access characters with indices 9, 10, 11 and so on.

Comment: Only if you know about the embedded nulls and how to read past them.  Assuming you fix the memory allocation, then: `fwrite(string1, sizeof(char), 13, stdout);` would write the first 13 bytes of `string1` to standard output (and you'd verify it worked by checking that the return value was 13).  This would include the null byte at index 10 but not the one at index 13.

Comment: @Jack thanks. I have wright the error now.

Comment: If it contains embedded null characters, then by definition it's not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can only write the embedded nulls if you know they're there and you know how long the data is by some means or another.  A string is formally defined as a sequence of bytes terminated by a (the first) null byte.  What you're seeking to write is not, therefore, a string as defined by the standard. However, assuming a C99 or C11 compiler (so that `i` can be declared in the `for` loop):

```
char *string1 = (char *)malloc(14 * sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    string1[i] = i + 65;
string1[10] = 0;
string1[11] = 65;
string1[12] = 67;
str[13] = 0;  
if (fwrite(string1, sizeof(char), 13, stdout) != 13)
    …deal with short write (error)…
```

If you're stuck with a C89 compiler, define `int i` outside the loop as you did in the question.

There are those who will excoriate you for including the cast in the call to `malloc()`.  It isn't necessary in Standard C (and you won't have a pre-standard C compiler unless you're working in an exceptionally unusual environment), but it doesn't do any harm as long as you have your compiler options set so that if you accidentally forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`, you will be told about it.  That should happen automatically with a C99 or C11 compiler in a standard-conforming mode.